# JavaScript Singleton and IntelliJ Idea

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, singleton

I'm having trouble with IntelliJ Idea's code completion and syntax checking and JavaScript.

I have the following (simplified) code for a Singleton object:

```
var MySingleton = new function() {
    var self = this;

    self.prop = "hello world";

    self.printHello = function() {
        console.log(self.prop);
    };
};

MySingleton.printHello();
```

The problem is, that IntelliJ complains at the last line about `Unresolved function or method printHello()`. It also will not suggest `printHello` when autocompleting from `MySingleton.`. The code itself works fine though.

I guess I have to either annotate or rewrite my code in a different style. But how?

Comment: What IJ version are you using?

Comment: Please try 15 EAP, seem like the problem is fixed there

Comment: @DennisUshakov Problem occurs again for IDEA 2020.1

Comment: My problem was fixed when I dropped the optional parentheses after the constructor function `new function() {};` vs  `new function() {}();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the module pattern is close to what I want to do and is well supported by Idea's code indexing:

```
var MySingleton = (function () {
    var self = this;

    var prop = "hello world";

    function printHello () {
        console.log(self.prop);
    };

    // export public functions
    return {
        printHello: printHello
    };
})();

MySingleton.printHello();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using factory to get Singeltons in Javascript.

```
var factory = function(){
    this.singelton = null;
    /**
     * @return MySingleton
     */
    function singelton(){
        if(this.singelton==null){
            this.singelton = new MySingelton();
        }
        return this.singleton;
    }
}

var instance_of_my_singleton = factory.singelton();
```